# Why when importing blender file .blend to unity3d it's not importing all the models/objects?

Tags: modeling, objects, export, import, unity

In the screenshot you can see that in the unity3d when i click on the parent object i see all the models/objects but most of them in orange and only some of them in red.

If i will not select the the parent object all the orange will not be show at all(second screenshot) only the red. And i checked the inspector of the red ones and the orange ones and both have same scale same material but for some reason after importing it from blender i can't see as objects in unity3d most of the models.

I have blender version 2.78 and i did in blender File > Save As and saved it as blender file. Then in unity in my project directory i coped the blender file to the Assets directory then dragged the blender file to the Hierarchy.

[image: Some red]

And

[image: Orange color objects not selected]

Not sure if the problem is in unity or with the blender, seems like in blender even that in blender i see all the models in red only in unity most of them orange/empty. I tried also in blender later to make File > Export > FBX (.fbx) but then when copying to the unity assets directory i get the same result as before.

Comment: At first glance it looks like inverted normals. Have you tried swapping their directions?

Comment: Yep looks like a normals issue. It also looks more like a question about Unity then Blender itself, probably better ask at the Unity community instead.